# how sort in java8 list of lists of object by multiple properties

Tags: java, java-8

I know this is not a new question but I want to sort CSV file by Column preferred in java8.

The Data-structure of CSV is `List<List<CsvEntity>` I need to sort first by one field of the CsvEntity then by other (not must) example by: `firstName` then by `lastName`.

```
class CsvEntity{
   private String firstName
   private String lastName
   private String address
}
```

Following this - [How to sort data in a CSV file using a particular field in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744670/how-to-sort-data-in-a-csv-file-using-a-particular-field-in-java)

What modifications do I need to make for supporting sort on multiple keys in Java8?

Comment: What do you want to sort? Elements in the outermost list? Or `CsvEntity` elements in nested lists?

Comment: This will help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761864/java-sort-list-of-lists

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769908/how-to-sort-the-name-along-with-age-in-java/54396193#54396193

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use comparator, an example of sorting by firstName then by lastName

```
list.forEach(l -> l.sort(Comparator.comparing(CsvEntity::getFirstName)
                               .thenComparing(CsvEntity::getLastName)));
```

Of course you have to have getters for your fields to use method reference

Answer (score 0):

```
        final Function<CsvEntity, String> byfirstName = CsvEntity -> CsvEntity.getfirstname();
        final Function<CsvEntity, String> bylastname = CsvEntity -> CsvEntity.getlastname();
        final Function<CsvEntity, String> byaddress = CsvEntity -> CsvEntity.getaddress(); 
        System.out.println("Sorted in ascending order by Firstname and Lastname: ");
        List<CsvEntity> sortedlist =   CsvEntity.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(byfirstName).thenComparing(bylastname))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```